# What does Serge Lang mean when he says $\mathbb{R}^4=\Bbb R^3\times \mathbb{R}^1$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Serge Lang equates $\mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{R}^2\times \Bbb R^2$ in terms of constructing a $4$ space, but intuitively, I'm am unable to understand the first case, where he takes $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3,x_4$ separately. The part where the $3$ coordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are considered separately with $x_4$ comes intuitively to me, to make a $4$ space.

Comment: “Serge Lang equates...”. Any reference?

Comment: In some algebraic text the spaces canonically isomorphic are consider equal

Comment: If you erase enough parentheses, they all consist of points with 4 real number entries.

Comment: Thank you (all). turns out I needed a lot more context before asking the question,  he expounds isomorphism later on in this book, hence the confusion.

Comment: I suspect that this was a typical mathematicial writer/teacher trick: He introduced this example as what, to most readers, would be an "obvious" example of the concept of an isomorphism, *even without yet defining that concept*, in order to motivate the formal definition of the concept. This trick has its own dangers, though --- some readers see through it!

Comment: You will be confronted with many vector spaces that are the same up to a change of notation. For example $(a,b,c,d)$ and $((a,b),(c,d))$ are identical up to a change of notation. Even something more exotic like $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ is the same vector space despite looking like a polynomial. All that matters is that we have a way to recover $a,b,c$ and $d$ from the notation to make a 4 dimensional vector space.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes sir, very true! I learned that one should use the text as a sort of pseudo-lecture series on the topic. once we do this, it makes sense to give an example before the concept itself, in my view, though annoying initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He’s most likely talking about vector space isomorphisms. The isomorphism in this case would be:

$T:\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 $,

$T((x_1,x_2,x_3),y) = ((x_1,x_2),(x_3,y))$.

It is easy to check this is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose the question was a waste since I hadn't had enough context on what I was reading. He expounds on this a bit later on the book.